# First observation by group using self-join

Tags: r, data.table, self-join

I'm trying to get the top row by a group of three variables using a data.table.

I have a working solution:

```
col1 <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
col2 <- c(2000,2000,2001,2001,2000,2000,2001,2001,2000,2000,2001,2001)
col4 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
data <- data.frame(store=col1,year=col2,month=12,sales=col4)

solution1 <- data.table(data)[,.SD[1,],by="store,year,month"]
```

I used the slower approach suggested by Matthew Dowle in the following link:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7884/fast-ways-in-r-to-get-the-first-row-of-a-data-frame-grouped-by-an-identifier

I'm trying to implement the faster self join but cannot get it to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: (+1) for a very nicely formulated question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### option 1 (using keys)

Set the key to be `store, year, month`

```
DT <- data.table(data, key = c('store','year','month'))
```

Then you can use `unique` to create a data.table containing the unique values of the key columns. By default this will take the first entry

```
unique(DT)
   store year month sales
1:     1 2000    12     1
2:     1 2001    12     3
3:     2 2000    12     5
4:     2 2001    12     7
5:     3 2000    12     9
6:     3 2001    12    11
```

But, to be sure, you could use a self-join with `mult='first'`. (other options are `'all'` or `'last'`)

```
# the key(DT) subsets the key columns only, so you don't end up with two 
# sales columns
DT[unique(DT[,key(DT), with = FALSE]), mult = 'first']
```

#### Option 2 (No keys)

Without setting the key, it would be faster to use `.I`  not `.SD`

```
DTb <- data.table(data)
DTb[DTb[,list(row1 = .I[1]), by = list(store, year, month)][,row1]]
```

Comment: (+1) That's much better than my answer; to directly obtain unique entries from the data.table thereby removing the necessity for `nomatch=0`.

Comment: +1 very cool, looks like it matches the "unique_together" index workings of MySQL.

Comment: It seems to me that the self-join is still faster on my large data.table (i.e. 40mm+ rows).  Thanks again

Comment: +1 too. I have a slight preference for `.I` for tasks like this, but the syntax bites because the pesky group columns get included in the result (when `drop` is added that'll be nicer). There is also a FR to make the natural `DT[,.SD[1],by="store,year,month"]` work quickly without any penalty of using `.SD` ([FR#2330](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2330&group_id=240&atid=978), so in future that'll be the idiomic way to `select top n * from` or `select 2nd from ...` etc

Comment: Has this functionality of `data.table` changed since this answer was posted? When I tried "Option 1" `unique(DT)` is just giving me back `DT` again?

Comment: @Adam  it appears that Matt's advice above is now functional: (`DT[,.SD[1],by="store,year,month"]`.  I just used this syntax to select the first of two records by person and date.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
solution2 <- data.table(data)[ , sales[1], by="store,year,month"]
> solution2
   store year month V1
1:     1 2000    12  1
2:     1 2001    12  3
3:     2 2000    12  5
4:     2 2001    12  7
5:     3 2000    12  9
6:     3 2001    12 11
```

I suppose you could rename that column:

```
data.table(data)[,fsales := sales[1],by="store,year,month"]
```

Comment: If you want to rename the column (and not add a column by reference) then `data.table(data)[,list(fsales = sales[1]),by="store,year,month"]` would be the way to go.