# R: find first non-NA observation in data.table column by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with many missing values and I want a variable which gives me a 1 for the first non-missin value in each group.

Say I have such a data.table:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(iris)[,.(Petal.Width,Species)]
DT[c(1:10,15,45:50,51:70,101:134),Petal.Width:=NA]
```

which now has missings in the beginning, at the end and in between. I have tried two versions, one is:

```
DT[min(which(!is.na(Petal.Width))),first_available:=1,by=Species]
```

but it only finds the global minimum (in this case, setosa gets the correct 1), not the minimum by group. I think this is the case because `data.table` first subsets by i, then sorts by group, correct? So it will only work with the row that is the global minimum of `which(!is.na(Petal.Width))` which is the first non-NA value.

A second attempt with the test in j:

```
DT[,first_available:= ifelse(min(which(!is.na(Petal.Width))),1,0),by=Species]
```

which just returns a column of 1s. Here, I don't have a good explanation as to why it doesn't work.

my goal is this:

```
DT[,first_available:=0]
DT[c(11,71,135),first_available:=1]
```

but in reality I have hundreds of groups. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776064/r-first-observation-by-group-using-data-table-self-join) question does come close but is not targeted at NA's and does not solve the issue here if I understand it correctly. I tried:

```
DT <- data.table(DT, key = c('Species'))
DT[unique(DT[,key(DT), with = FALSE]), mult = 'first']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: first observation by group using data.table & self-join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776064/r-first-observation-by-group-using-data-table-self-join)

Comment: see edit, I'm not sure

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
DT[!is.na(Petal.Width), first := as.integer(seq_len(.N) == 1L), by = Species]
```

Comment: nice, this one also preserves NA's in between, that might be handy

Comment: Hey looks, good, can you explain this part of your code `seq_len(.N)`

Comment: `.N` is a special symbol that holds the number of observations for each group. And `seq_len` constructs a sequence from 1 to .N. See `?data.table` for `.N` and other special symbols, and `?seq_len` for more.

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
DT[DT[, .I[which.max(!is.na(Petal.Width))] , Species]$V1, 
     first_available := 1][is.na(first_available), first_available := 0]
```

Or a slightly more compact option is

```
DT[, first_available := as.integer(1:nrow(DT) %in% 
      DT[, .I[!is.na(Petal.Width)][1L], by = Species]$V1)][]
```

Comment: great, this does what I'm looking for. I'll catch up on .I and 1L

Answer (score -1):

```
  > DT[!is.na(DT$Petal.Width) & DT$first_available == 1]
  #      Petal.Width    Species first_available
  #   1:         0.2     setosa               1
  #   2:         1.8 versicolor               1
  #   3:         1.4  virginica               1

  > rownames(DT)[!is.na(DT$Petal.Width) & DT$first_available == 1]
  # [1] "11"  "71"  "135"

  > rownames(DT)[!is.na(DT$Petal.Width) & DT$first_available == 0]
  # [1] "12"  "13"  "14"  "16"  "17"  "18"  "19"  "20"  "21"  "22"  "23"  "24" 
  # [13] "25"  "26"  "27"  "28"  "29"  "30"  "31"  "32"  "33"  "34"  "35"  "36" 
  # [25] "37"  "38"  "39"  "40"  "41"  "42"  "43"  "44"  "72"  "73"  "74"  "75" 
  # [37] "76"  "77"  "78"  "79"  "80"  "81"  "82"  "83"  "84"  "85"  "86"  "87" 
  # [49] "88"  "89"  "90"  "91"  "92"  "93"  "94"  "95"  "96"  "97"  "98"  "99" 
  # [61] "100" "136" "137" "138" "139" "140" "141" "142" "143" "144" "145" "146"
  # [73] "147" "148" "149" "150"
```

Comment: but this assumes I already have the answer, no? `first_available` is what I'm trying to get, I just built it manually at the end to show what I'm aiming for.

Comment: also, is it not considered bad style to mix `data.table` and `data.frame` syntax? I do it once in a while for simplicity as well so I'm not sure. What do you think?

Comment: Oops, just checked. I was trying your first_available and then it was there in DT, My stupidity. I am doing by dataframe way. Editing my answer in a while.